# Encrypt string from XML within XSLT Stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, encryption

Is it possible to encrypt a string in an XML dokument when applying an XSLT stylesheet?

This is a template I use:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <div class="tgPropertyInput tgLangDE">
        <div class="tgLabel" id="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
        </div>
        <div lang="de" contentEditable="true" class="tgInput" id="{concat(local-name(), '_input')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

The content of `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` is what I want to encrypt in a way that I can decrypt it within javascript. The Idea behind this is that I generate persisted HTML versions of an XML file. These are used internally but potentially send to some customers. Some of the fields should not be readable by the customer. So I would encrypt them and have the script for decryption on a local server.

Comment: XSLT allows to write a user defined function (UDF) in Javascript, and some other languages. So you can write such embedded UDF to encrypt the values and call it in the relevant XSLT spots to obfuscate the data.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky XSLT allows processors to provide extension functions. Some processors (well, actually one processor) support extensions written in Javascript. That is entirely optional and not part of the XSLT standard.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, let's wait for clarifications regarding the extension function languages support in the unknown for us XSLT engine from the person who posted the question. At least we provided a general direction where the real answer could be.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I'm using Saxon 9HE

Comment: Saxon 9 HE exists in different versions, the original product is based on the Oracle Java platform and allows you to call into any Java library using the extension mechanism documented at http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensibility/integratedfunctions/. So you can certainly access any encryption library available to Java if you use the Java version of Saxon 9 HE. For the .NET version you can access any .NET API using the mechanism described in http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensibility/integratedfunctions/ext-fns-N.html.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Any of this comments should be a proper answer.